# If $U_i$ is open in $S_i\subseteq X$ then it is open in $S:=\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$ too.

Tags: general-topology

> **Statement**
>
> If $U_i$ is open in $S_i\subseteq X$ then $V\cap S$ is open in $S:=\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$ when $V$ is open in $X$

So I know that if $U_j$ is for any $j\in I$ open in $S_j$ then there exist for each $i\in I$ an open set $A_j$ such that $U_j=A_j\cap S_j$ but unfortunately I think that generally $A_j\cap S\neq U_j$ so I conclude that generally the statement could be false but I am not completely sure about this. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question in the title:

This is not true. Let $S_1=[0,1], S_2=\mathbb R \setminus [0,1]$ and $U_1=[0,1]$. Then $U_1$ is open in $S_1$ but not in $S_1 \cup S_2$.

For the  other question, $V \cap S$ is open in $S$ if $V$ is open in $X$. This has nothing to do wth the $U_i$'s.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your last statement: could you explain better, please?

Comment: Anyway I'm asking what happens if $S_i$ is open for each $i\in I$. What can you say about?

Comment: Your question is to show that $V \cap S$ is open in $S$ when $V$ is open in $X$, right? This is true by definition of the subspace topology of $S$.  @Ladarious

Comment: Okay, so if $S_i$ is open for each $i\in I$ then $U_i$ is a open set contained in the open set $S$ so that we conclude that $U_i$ is open in $S$ too, right?

Comment: @Ladarious Yes,that is correct.